# CDE and AIX nothing work

Tags: aix, vnc

On other unix systems,simply set "dtsession" on .xstartup file of vnc
start the cde session.
On aix i have this problem when i start the session,appear only an error message

```
The DT messaging system could not be started
to correct the problem
1. Choose ok to return to the login screen
2. Select Failsave session from the login screen's option menu and login.
3. Check to see that the hostname is correct in:
/etc/hosts
Other hostname problems can be corrected by using the command:
smit mktcpip
4. For additional info, see the DT User's Guide.
```

I make some checks
hostname  report correct hostname   OK
hostname -s report correct hostname short OK
dig myhostname report correctly,also dig -x ip report OK
I have set also order local,bind in /etc/netsvc.conf
I forgot,i'm on vnc,and i have set xstartup like this

```
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
#xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &

exec /usr/dt/bin/dtsession &
```

As suggested [here](https://version7x.wordpress.com/2009/05/18/installing-cde-in-aix/) 
i also did

```
cp /usr/dt/appconfig/types/C/* ~/.dt/types/
```

But nothing

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: You probably did the basic checks already, like if the necessary filesets are installed and that the CDE dtlogin daemon is already running?

Apart from that, there's a pretty detailed guide on how to enable a full CDE session via VNC: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/Power%20Systems/page/Launching%20a%20VNC%20CDE%20session%20via%20AIX%20inetd
You may also want to look at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/wikis/home?lang=en#!/wiki/Power%20Systems/page/X-Windows%20on%20AIX

Comment: try those guide,none works anyway thanks for suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: a bad .profile or .bashrc try with another user "virgin" and all works fine.
Problem was UTF8,a solution can be to export another language on xstartup